# First conditional sentences

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Certain grammar websites describe type 1 conditional sentences as the ones in which the time is the **present** or **future** and the situation is real.

Examples given are:

- If I have time, I'll finish that letter.
- What will you do if you miss the plane?
- Nobody will notice if you make a mistake.
- If you drop that glass, it will break.
- If you don't drop the gun, I'll shoot!
- If you don't leave, I'll call the police.

I wish to ask "In what circumstances the above sentence examples can refer to present time as defined above since they all appear to be referring to the future"?

Answer (score 1):

In type 1 conditional sentences

1. The tense in 'if' clause is always      simple present.
2. The tense in the main clause is simple future.

So all your given examples are correct and according to the definition.

Answer (score -1):

In all the examples given, the time of the situation in the *if...* part is in the future. A future-time *if...* usually has a non-modal present tense in open conditionals (those not viewed as counter-factual or unlikely). (CaGEL p744)

Comment: DW 256 why can't the time be present as stated in the definition if the time of action is 'Now'(present moment) of course, it can be referring to the future also if the time of action will be after now.

Comment: This is not something that is dictated by the grammar but interpreted through context. E.g. _If I get to work early, I'll (usually) chat with the security guards_ has modal auxiliary _will_  in the apodosis (resultant situation) but is describing a habitual situation, what this person has a tendency to do. In that case, it would be interpreted as a present state of affairs. The most likely readings, out of context, for the examples provided is an epistemic (what the speaker thinks likely) interpretation for modal auxiliary _will_ which would put these in the future.

Comment: My point is also that the time reference is decided by context. When one says"Please leave this place. If you don't leave, I'll call the police".By context, he is talking about his present order/threat and not future time.

Comment: His leaving will be at some time after the utterance, in the future. The threat is also a prediction of what he will do, again in the future, if the person doesn't leave. The only part that could be interpreted as in the present is _will_ as a marker of what the speaker thinks likely, which makes sense as English doesn't have a future tense. In any case, the two actions referenced, _leaving_ and _shooting_ will all occur after the utterance and hence in the future.

Comment: Isn't there a time difference between person ordering to leave(present)and action by the person ordered to leave(future)which obviously will be the time after the utterance. Isn't the sentence here about the person ordering(now) and accordingly, the present time .

Comment: If it were about the act of ordering then it would need another verb to indicate that and it would have to be rephrased, e.g.  _The man **orders** him to leave and **threatens** to shoot him if he doesn't_ . / _I **order** you to leave_ . / _The police officer **threatens**, "If you don't get out now, I'll shoot you."_ etc.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define "the present". Literally, that refers to the moment we are in, but how large is that moment? You can slice it up as small as you want and it will still have a length that we pass through. By the same token, you can consider events that might technically be "the very near future" to be in the present. A the  robber is in  future I mean "now" as in the colloquial, general understanding of "now", as soon as possible, even if the precise moment of my call is a few seconds into the future. The situation of an intruder is present and pressing, don't you think? Bu